# Tweaking the common-lisp reader

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to parse a s-exp based langage and I am trying to prototype it using Common-Lisp, however, the reader has quite a few reader macros already defined that are getting in my way.

I have this macro, which basically does seem to work and do what I want, that is temporarily disabling some reader macros and enable case-sensitivity so that I don't have to escape things, currently I disable `quote` and `multiple escape`.

```lisp
(defmacro with-custom-reader (&body body)
  "Enable case sensitivity and disable some reader macros while performing
a READ."
  `(let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
     (loop for cc across "|'" do
       (set-macro-character
        cc
        (lambda (stream char)
          (concatenate
           'string
           (make-string 1 :initial-element char)
           (loop
             for c = (peek-char nil stream nil nil)
             while (and c (eql c (peek-char t stream nil nil)))
             collect (read-char stream) into letters
             finally (return (coerce letters 'string)))))
        t *readtable*))
     (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)
     (progn
       ,@body)))
```

Is there a better way, or does this macro may have some unintended side-effects? I also welcome any remarks concerning the style or the indentation.